# Implementing time delay function in C

Tags: c, delay

I want to implement a delay function using null loops. But the amount of time needed to complete a loop once is compiler and machine dependant. I want my program to determine the time on its own and delay the program for the specified amount of time. Can anyone give me any idea how to do this?
N. B. There is a function named delay() which suspends the system for the specified milliseconds. Is it possible to suspend the system without using this function?

Comment: The delay() function is os and machine dependent. Its not some magical function of the C language, it is just a standard interface adopted by either ANSI or POSIX. It has to be implemented on the kernel level for specific hardware meaning it also is (compiler/machine dependent).

Comment: If you are not on a kernel level of programming, ie user app in unix, windows etc, why reinvent the wheel? If you are on a kernel level you would have to know the hardware on how to use registers with timers etc.

Comment: As of C11, the standard now proposes an interface that is independent of the OS, `thrd_sleep`. Unfortunately not all compilers implement that, yet, but is coming.

Comment: Something like usleep()/nanosleep() in Linux or Sleep() in Windows will certainly work, but my experience is that anytime you think you want a delay like that in a program, it's because you haven't put enough thought into what you really need. What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should **never** sit in a loop doing nothing. Not only does it waste energy (as it keeps your CPU 100% busy counting your loop counter) -- in a multitasking system it also decreases the whole system performance, because your process is getting *time slices* all the time as it *appears* to be doing something.

Next point is ... I don't know of any `delay()` function. This is not standard C. In fact, until C11, there was no standard at all for things like this.

POSIX to the rescue, there is [`usleep(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep) (deprecated) and [`nanosleep(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep). If you're on a POSIX-compliant system, you'll be fine with those. They *block* (means, the scheduler of your OS knows they have nothing to do and schedules them only after the end of the call), so you don't waste CPU power.

If you're on windows, for a direct delay in code, you only have [`Sleep()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx). Note that THIS function takes milliseconds, but has normally only a precision around 15ms. Often good enough, but not always. If you need better precision on windows, you can request more timer interrupts using [`timeBeginPeriod()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd757624(v=vs.85).aspx) ... `timeBeginPeriod(1);` will request a timer interrupt each millisecond. Don't forget calling [`timeEndPeriod()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd757626(v=vs.85).aspx) with *the same value* as soon as you don't need the precision any more, because more timer interrupts come with a cost: they keep the system busy, thus wasting more energy.

I had a somewhat similar problem developing a little game recently, I needed constant ticks in 10ms intervals, this is what I came up with [for POSIX-compliant systems](https://github.com/Zirias/cursedsnake/blob/master/src/platform/posix/ticker.c) and [for windows](https://github.com/Zirias/cursedsnake/blob/master/src/platform/win32/ticker.c). The `ticker_wait()` function in this code just suspends until the next tick, maybe this is helpful if your original intent was some timing issue.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're on a real-time operating system, anything you program yourself directly is not going to be accurate.  You need to use a system function to sleep for some amount of time like `usleep` in Linux or `Sleep` in Windows.

Because the operating system could interrupt the process sooner or later than the exact time expected, you should get the system time before and after you sleep to determine how long you actually slept for.

Edit:

On Linux, you can get the current system time with `gettimeofday`, which has microsecond resolution (whether the actual clock is that accurate is a different story).  On Windows, you can do something similar with `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`:

```
int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz)
{
    const unsigned __int64 epoch_diff = 11644473600000000;
    unsigned __int64 tmp;
    FILETIME t;

    if (tv) {
        GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&t);

        tmp = 0;
        tmp |= t.dwHighDateTime;
        tmp <<= 32;
        tmp |= t.dwLowDateTime;

        tmp /= 10;
        tmp -= epoch_diff;
        tv->tv_sec = (long)(tmp / 1000000);
        tv->tv_usec = (long)(tmp % 1000000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you taking about using the time() function to get the system time?

Comment: `gettimeofday(2)` is obsolescent since SUS v4; you should be recommending `clock_gettime(2)`.

Comment: And also: using a system function to sleep is not necessarily more accurate than rolling your own. As you said, Linux is not a real-time operating system, so delays can (and will) always happen no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like find the exact time it is at a point in time and then keep it in a while loop which rechecks the time until it gets to whatever the time you want. Then it just breaks out and continue executing the rest of your program.  I'm not sure if I see much of a benefit in looping rather than just using the delay function though.