# Difference between delay() and sleep() in C?

Tags: c, delay, sleep

Both delay() and sleep() function suspends the system for some amount of time, delay takes milisecond as argument while sleep takes second as argument. Besides this, is there any differences between these two functions? And among them, which gives more accurate result?

Comment: Neither of these is a standard library function. Which library are you referring to?

Comment: I think normally `sleep()` sets the processor free during sleep time, while `delay()` needs CPU-usage, but I'm not quite sure about it.

Comment: Dos.h has both the functions

Comment: Dos.h is not a part of the standard library. And both functions guarantee only that approximate delay will be made. All other side effects are implementation defined.

Comment: If you didn't understand the answer I gave to your OTHER question about this, how about asking there in the comments?

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Link? If that is a dup it should be closed.

Comment: @Olaf not exactly a duplicate, just obviously the same underlying problem: [Implementing time delay function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548460/implementing-time-delay-function-in-c)

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Found already. I agree that you already answered mostly, but not for `delay()`, so this is not really a duplicate. You might just c/p art of your other answer and add the part about `delay()`, I think.

Comment: Well like this ... suddenly mentioning `dos.h` implies this question is about `MS DOS`. Something nobody would *expect* nowadays. @RohanGayen you should make these things explicit and add proper tags ... neither `delay()` nor `sleep()` are standard C functions.

Answer (score 2):

They do the same thing except one sleeps for number of seconds while the other sleeps for milliseconds.

You should go with [Reference to std::this_thread::sleep_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for):

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for
```

instead in c++ if you can. windows.h have Sleep and unix have usleep.

This is another implementation found online that might better fit your needs:

```
#if defined(__WIN32__) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32) || defined(__WINDOWS__) || defined(__TOS_WIN__)

  #include <windows.h>

  inline void delay( unsigned long ms )
    {
    Sleep( ms );
    }

#else  /* presume POSIX */

  #include <unistd.h>

  inline void delay( unsigned long ms )
    {
    usleep( ms * 1000 );
    }

#endif
```

Comment: I am guessing that he is using Borland Turbo C++ 3.0, so he won't have `<thread>`.

Answer (score 0):

Sleep relinquishes the CPU for specified amount  , so that other process can execute.
While Delay is just busy waiting for the amount to expire and then continue once expires, it do not execute any other process during this period.

Comment: Could you please provide the source?